# Charged nucleophile and SN1/E1/SN2/E2 reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

How can we say that if a charged nucleophile/base is present we can safely rule out the possibility that the reaction can take place via SN1/E1 mechanism? I have been trying to figure this out since hours. Help would be appreciated. Thank you. [Source](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2012/11/30/deciding-sn1sn2e1e2-2-the-nucleophilebase/)

Comment: Could you please take a little more time to expand your question and add more details? It's pretty cryptic right now (at least for me).

Comment: I have added all I could. To see from where my problem arose-check the link.

Comment: It says so in rule 3: you cannot form a carbocation for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Strong nucleophiles tend to undergo S<sub>N</sub>1/E1 reactions whereas weak nucleophiles *tend* to undergo S<sub>N</sub>1/E1 reactions.

An increase in electron density will make a nucleophile stronger. This effect can be clearly seen when conjugate bases of common nucleophiles are stronger than the nuclephiles themselves. For example: $\ce{NH_2^- > NH_3} $.

In S<sub>N</sub>1/E1 reactions, the weak nucleophile can only attack the carbocation once the leaving group has left. This is precisely because it is a weak nucleophile.

IN S<sub>N</sub>2/E2 reactions, the strong nucleophile attacks the carbon before it can even form a carbocation. This forces the leaving group to leave. This is precisely because it is a strong nucleophile.